# Disabling SMS notifications except in the top bar

Tags: sms

Whenever I receive an SMS I have 3 on-screen notifications. How can I disable them without disabling the notification in the top bar?

[image]

Text program/menu/settings/notifications/uncheck only disable the notification in the top bar, which I don't want:

[image]

I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.